# Closed-form expression for $\sum_{j=0}^k \binom{n+j-1}{j} a^j b^{k-j}$?

Tags: binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

Let $a_1,a_2 \in \mathbb{R}$, and let $n,k$ be positive integers. Is there a closed-form expression for $\sum_{j=0}^k \binom{n+j-1}{j} a_1^j a_2^{k-j}$?

Context: This quantity looks very similar to that appearing in the Binomial theorem: $\sum_{j=0}^k \binom{k}{j} a_1^j a_2^{k-j}=(a_1+a_2)^k.$ I have encountered this quantity in the following combinatorial problem:

Let $\mu_1=a_2, \mu_2=\dots=\mu_{n+1}=a_1$. Then the desired quantity is equal to the sum of the elements of the following multiset:  $\{\mu_{i_1}\cdots \mu_{i_k} : i_1 \leq i_2 \leq \dots \leq i_k \in [n]\}$.

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Context added. Thanks

Comment: There is a formula (which hides a summation) but it involves the Gaussian hypegeometric function. Did you already hear about them ?

Comment: I have heard of Gaussian hypergeometric functions. Can you write down the formula? This would be helpful.

Comment: Note that unlike the binomial formula where adding more terms would make no difference, the upper bound in your summation is of vital importance, so this is not a problem of the same nature. You expect a result that depends on two parameters, $n$ and  $k$ (apart from $a,b$ which you could treat as indeterminates).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\sum_{j=0}^{k}\binom{n+j-1}{j}\ a^jb^{k-j}=\frac{b^{n+k}}{(a-b)^n}-\frac{1}{b}\binom{n+k}{k+1}\ a^{k+1}\ _2F_1(1,k+1+n;\,k+2;\,\frac {a}{b})$$

$_2F_1$ is a [generalized hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_hypergeometric_function).

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** There is no closed-form expression available. But if you are familiar with the *[binomial series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)* recall the binomial identity
\begin{align*}
\binom{p+q-1}{q}=(-1)^q\binom{-p}{q}
\end{align*}
and consider
\begin{align*}
b^k\left(1-\frac{a}{b}\right)^{-n}
\end{align*}
to find a relationship with your sum.